# How to check if request came with the right ssl certificate

Tags: php, ssl

I have a php file on a server. Some service will send requests to this file and i want to check if the variables: `SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY, SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O, SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_L, SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN, SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_C, SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_O, SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_CN, SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_C` 
has the right values.

How to check them in PHP?

Comment: How is your PHP connected with the SSL layer? I assume via your webserver, so please list how you would obtain these values within / from your webserver first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Apache Httpd, you should be able to get access to the [SSL environment variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#envvars) using [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) (for example `$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN']`).

You'll also need to make sure your [`SSLOptions`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#ssloptions) directive is configured accordingly for these variables to be used.

Comment: Could You tell me how to configure SSLOptions ? Now when I display `$_SERVER` it doesn't contains any of the SSL variables

Comment: Just like it says in the first paragraph of the documentation I've linked to: `SSLOptions StdEnvVars`.